# Conditional Formatting IF/AND Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

**EDIT 2:**
Test document. See comment of what I'm trying to accomplish in cell A1.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lqrPbVqSrO257PqOYKLuCTxG1iiLaL6KYawp1hu4n5c/edit#gid=0

**EDIT:**
I've tried this code and it doesn't operate correctly. It highlights some cells, but not all within the range, and doesn't operate the duplicate identification correctly.

```
=if(and($I5=false), countifs($L:L, L1)>1)
```

**Original post:**

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight a row when the following conditions are met:

The value of cell `$I1="FALSE"` (i.e. the box in the cell is unchecked)

AND

The value in `$L1` has at least one duplicate value in column `L`.

I am currently using the following formula to only highlight the duplicate values, but cannot get it to function along with the secondary condition of `$I1=FALSE`.

For the range `K:L` (It doesn't allow me to highlight the whole row for some reason)

```
=countif($L:L,L1)>1
```

I also have an additional formatting rule in place that is working as I want it to:

```
=$I1=TRUE
```

This is highlighting the row a different color once the checkbox in column `I` is checked.

Comment: Welcome to Webapps. Please include a sample spreadsheet with what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to access your spreadsheet, but according with your report the conditional formatting formula that you're looking for is this:

`=AND(EQ($I$1,FALSE),EQ(countif($L:L,$L$1)>1,TRUE))`